# How do fix height of row in SPGridview?(do't wrap row)

Tags: web-part, spgridview

I have a Spgridview. I created columns in page-load .

When bind it, the height of row is different. Its height varies based on the content within it.

How do fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find :)

```
   e.Row.Height = new Unit(25);
            if (grid.Columns.Count > 1)
                for (int i = 1; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Wrap = false;
```